# Uncaught runtime error (bootstrap_data_image)

Tags: typescript, error-handling, runtime-error, runtime

I got an error in the console and on the screen:

[image]

I'm using antd library, and here is some bootstrap error. We are not using bootstrap.
I have no idea what to do. Already deleted node_modules and yarn.lock file, but this didn't help.